# php function gives unexpected output

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to count the word "online" in an array with keys and values.

```
function p($a){
    function printAllVals($a, $val) {
      if (!is_array($a)) {
        if ($a == "online"){
            $val+=1;
            echo $val;
            //echo $a  <-- this prints online 5 times
        }
          return;
       }
       foreach($a as $k => $v) {   
           printAllVals($v, $val);
       }  
    }
    printAllVals($a, 0);
}
```

it prints "online" 5 times when echoed `$a`, but when the $val prints "1" 5 times.
Seems like it's taking the original value of `$val` when the function is called. What have I done wrong?

$a is the array and it's like the following(multi dimensional):

```
prod:
        cluster:
            csddb:
                inst_1: online
                inst_2: online
            oiddb:
                inst1: online
                inst2: offline
        local:
            quoid:
                inst_1: offline
                inst_2: offline
            qaprod:
                inst_1: offline
                inst_2: offline
```

Sorry for the incomplete question.

Comment: What's the input data that you're testing with?

Comment: @dragoste It's something like the following but longer.
prod:
        cluster:
            csddb:
                inst_1: online
                inst_2: online
            oiddb:
                inst1: online
                inst2: offline
        local:
            quoid:
                inst_1: offline
                inst_2: offline
            qaprod:
                inst_1: offline
                inst_2: offline

Comment: Please update it in your post in proper format.

Comment: Is `$a` an array or a string?

Comment: @d.coder updated, sorry for that

Comment: @MathewsMathai $a is the array and i edited the question. Sorry

Comment: @TAS In the above code $val variable have only local scope inside printAllVals. Try to change the code to $val = printAllVals($v, $val);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is recursion. So when recursion back to previous state it also backs to previous values so you loose state of `$val`; You must just return `$val`:

```
    function printAllVals($a, $val) {
      if (!is_array($a)) {
        if ($a == "online"){
            $val+=1;
            echo $val;
//            echo $a;
        }
          return $val;
       }
       foreach($a as $k => $v) {   
           $val = printAllVals($v, $val);
       } 
       return $val;
    }
    printAllVals($a, 0);
```